# How do I know if there is internal resistance in an LED?

Tags: led, diodes

So I have a circuit that seems to defy all that I know about LEDs.

I cut apart 2 flashlights that run on one 1.5v battery each with a variable resistor (0 to 50 ohm) to change brightness. I am now running them off of a 12V battery with leads connected to their battery terminals. In testing they both come on if I connect them in series with 1.5v and no resistor and draw 25mA which is strange because I thought you needed to double the voltage if you double the LEDs.

Since there was no resistor and they didn't burn up that implies that 1.5/2 is the voltage drop of the diode but then why didn't they burn up with 1.5v and no resistor across just one of them? What is going on with these?

Comment: There's no reason you can't fit a current limiter on the same die as the emitter.

Comment: Are you saying that two LEDs run in series from a 1.5V source? That seems pretty low.

Comment: There is a region where a diode can run without a resistor. Further you are probably using an alkaline battery. These batteries have a decent internal resistance which is probably helping.

Comment: Please add a drawing of this, it's pretty hard to follow. That and having to read "resister" so many times makes my brain hurt. :)

Comment: I have edited your question to add a modicum of punctuation, capitalization, spelling and formatting. This will hopefully give you an example to follow the next time you post a question.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you are actually doing, since you mention a 12V battery and then mention a 1.5 volt battery with the two circuits in series...not sure what the 12V battery, if any, is doing, or not doing.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the 12v is what i eventually want to run them off of. but i need to know what the circuit is (if any) inside the flashlight since it dose not seem to be behaving as i would expect from just LEDs. I'm not sure what the best path forward is for connecting to 12V without knowing why it behaves the way it dose.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev yes, i thought so too. which is another reason why im so confused. something else must be going on inside the flashlight but what? and how can i safely connect them to a 12v supply?

Comment: You can estimate their forward drop by looking at similar data sheets, assuming you don't have the one for yours and adding a little more resistance. Use the equation I wrote in my answer, except now there's 2x the led voltage drop.

Answer (score 3):

LED's do have some internal resistance. Without consulting or knowing the data sheets for your particular components, I suspect what's happening is because you've got 2 in series, there's very little current because most of the voltage is being dropped. Typically in an led circuit, the equation to calculate current is

i=(Vsupply-Vled)/R

Where Vsupply is your input voltage and Vled is your LED's forward voltage drop. This can vary and really depends on the LED used and you'd need to consult the datasheets of the LED. You can read more about it [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/219). With 2 Leds in series, it probably approaches the full 1.5v drop. Most LED's have voltage drops larger than 1.5V for full conduction. So there's very little current because the LED isn't fully conducting yet and this is why it's the case with either 1 or 2 LED's in series. A resistor would only need to be added when the LED has reached full conduction, which will be when Vsupply>Vled

Comment: that makes a lot more sense. i always thought if the led wasn't "fully conducting" it wouldn't light up at all.

Answer (score 0):

An LED flashlight (white, or even red) that operates on a single 1.5V battery is almost certainly using some sort of voltage boost circuit (i.e. a blocking oscillator s.k.a. "joule thief" more popularly, or some other configuration wiht the same effect.)

This would be rather different in behavior from a "bare" LED.

Comment: if there is some kind of extra circuit inside what would you recommend to run them off of a 12v supply? would the normal drop resister calculations not work? would i need to used a 1.5v regulator?